# How do I insert spatial data into a table contains road column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error message while I am trying to insert my data into line table, using coordinates for points between road segments.

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "SRID=27700;LINESTRING((5" <-- parse error at position 24 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

Part of my code:

```
NSERT INTO public."RoadSegments"("no", "seg_ID", "description", "location", "length", "the_geom")
VALUES 

(1,'Seg_1','Shephards Bush to Royal Crescent','Shephards Bush','540',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING((51.504593 -0.220437),(51.505233 -0.214105))')),
(2,'Seg_2','Royal Crescent to Norland Square','Notting Hill','306',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING((51.505233 -0.214105),(51.506053 -0.209956))')),
(3,'Seg_3','Norland Square to Holland Park','Notting Hill','383',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING((51.506053 -0.209956),(51.507575 -0.204795))')),
(4,'Seg_4','Holland Park to Notting Hill Gate','Notting Hill','477',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING((51.507575 -0.204795),(51
```

Comment: Your sql code is missing `LINESTRING((51.507575 -0.204795),(51`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have too much parentheses in your LINESTRING parameters. Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO public."RoadSegments"("no", "seg_ID", "description", "location", "length", "the_geom")
VALUES 

(1,'Seg_1','Shephards Bush to Royal Crescent', 'Shephards Bush','540',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING(51.504593 -0.220437,51.505233 -0.214105)')),
(2,'Seg_2','Royal Crescent to Norland Square', 'Notting Hill',  '306',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING(51.505233 -0.214105,51.506053 -0.209956)')),
(3,'Seg_3','Norland Square to Holland Park',   'Notting Hill',  '383',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING(51.506053 -0.209956,51.507575 -0.204795)')),
(4,'Seg_4','Holland Park to Notting Hill Gate','Notting Hill',  '477',ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=27700;LINESTRING(51.507575 -0.204795,51 ...              '))
```

This should be the correct syntax (no extra parentheses around the coordinates)

Comment: ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "SRID=27700;LINESTRING((5" <-- parse error at position 24 within geometry
SQL state: XX000

Comment: @RADHIAYYASH *sigh*... you still have two parentheses here before the 5: `SRID=27700;LINESTRING((5`